# Aligning inline blocks at top

Tags: html, css

I have these three checklist areas that I would like to align together at the top. However, they seem to align at the bottom. Can anyone help with this. My code is on a JSFIDDLE.

http://jsfiddle.net/rynslmns/7H5MA/

HTML

```
<div id="list1">
   <h7>Basic Qualifications</h7>
   <ul class="fa-ul">
      <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>21 years of Age</li>
      <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>20/20 Vision with or without corrective lenses</li>
      <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>Able to lift 50 lbs</li>
      <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>Has a friendly face</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="list2">
   <h7>Background Check</h7>
   <ul class="fa-ul">
      <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>No violent crimes</li>
      <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>No sexual offenses</li>
      <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>No theft</li>
      <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>No felonies</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div id="list3">
   <h7>Motor Vehicle</h7>
   <ul class="fa-ul">
      <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>21 with Valid US driver’s license for 1 or more years</li>
      <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>Valid personal Auto Insurance that meets or exceeds state requirement</li>
      <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>Not more than 2  minor Moving violations in past 3 years (minor accident, failure to stop at stop sign)</li>
      <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>No major moving violations</li>
      <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>No DUI or other drug-related driving violations</li>
      <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>No Felonies or other drastic infractions in driver’s lifetime driving history</li>
      <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>All other Reckless driving habits as buddyTruk sees fit</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#list1 {
  display:inline-block; 
  width:33%; 
  background-color:red;
} 
#list2 {
  display:inline-block; 
  width:33%; 
  background-color:red;
} 
#list3 {
  display:inline-block; 
  width:33%; 
  background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `vertical-align:top` on each element.

This works because they are inline elements with a default `vertical-align` value of `baseline`.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gqWsj/)

```
#list1, #list2, #list3 {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @JoshC. I know it was a stupid question, I am just getting into basic html and css. Ill accept your answer when the time window is up.

Answer (score 1):

add the style `vertical-align:top;` to each of the list elements